# Compiling FFmpeg staticly using NDK with openssl

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, openssl, configure

I have been trying to compile ffmpeg into a static library in order to use it in my android application, but i couldn't get it to work.

Im working with FFmpeg 3.2.4, and ndk r13b, using bash on windows 10(Ubuntu 14.04).

Here is what i did:

- I made a stand alone toolchain for x86_64 and api 21 using:
  `python make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 21 --arch x86_64 --install-dir {}`
- Made a configuration script:

  ```
  ./configure \
  --target-os=android                                     \
  --arch=x86_64                                              \
  --prefix=/home/david/ffmpeg_x86_64_build                          \
  --cross-prefix=/home/david/x86_64_toolchain/bin/x86_64-linux-android-\
  --sysroot=/home/david/x86_64_toolchain/sysroot                    \
  --enable-cross-compile                                  \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static"                           \
  --enable-ffmpeg                                         \
  --disable-ffplay                                        \
  --disable-ffprobe                                       \
  --disable-ffserver                                      \
  --disable-doc                                           \
  --disable-htmlpages                                     \
  --disable-manpages                                      \
  --disable-podpages                                      \
  --disable-txtpages                                      \
  --extra-cflags="-fPIC"                                  \
  --extra-cxxflags="-fPIC"
  --disable-shared --enable-static \
  --enable-yasm

  make
  make install
  ```

It produced an FFmpeg executable, however when i ran it on my API 23 emulator, i got an error message:`error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.`
Even that i used -fPic

How can i fix it ? Also i'm not sure about my configuration, there wasn't up to date sources on how to compile it correctly for every ABI (arm,arm64,x86,x86_64,mips,mips64) that i need for my application.
I have seen many script, and im not too familiar with compiling native code, so i wasn't sure what settings i need, for example like C flags and etc.

To be precise on how i tried to configure FFmpeg :

- I need a static library
- I Only need the ffmpeg command line utility
- I want to compile the library for every ABI i listed above.This configuration tried to compile for x86_64.
- Running on android of course

I would greatly appreciate some help on how to configure and compile this correctly.

## EDIT

Thanks to @Alex Cohn i have been able to compile ffmpeg, however i couldn't get it to compile using --enable-ssl however i have been faced with a problem.

Since we are providing a system root, the compiler won't look for files on my host machine, so we will need need to compile ssl for android from source.
I have used this library [OpenSSL-For-Android](https://github.com/pstanoev/OpenSSL-For-Android), and used the precompiled library.

I added to the configure file these lines:

```
--extra-cflags='-m32  -fPIE -I./OpenSSL-For-Android/openssl-1.0.2j/include' \
--extra-ldflags='-m32 -Wl,-eh-frame-hdr -Wl,-m,elf_i386 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -fPIE -pie -L./OpenSSL-For-Android/openssl-1.0.2j/lib/x86'
```

I tried telling the config, that it should search for the headers of openssl here, and that it should link against this library here.

But it fails on this test as stated on config.log:

```
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.JVeoLDmr.c
    1   extern int SSL_library_init();
    2   int main(void){ SSL_library_init(); }
END /tmp/ffconf.JVeoLDmr.c
/home/david/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc --sysroot=/home/david/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/ -isysroot /home/david/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -m32 -fPIE -I./OpenSSL-For-Android/openssl-1.0.2j/include -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -pthread -c -o /tmp/ffconf.x5yr8e11.o /tmp/ffconf.JVeoLDmr.c
/home/david/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -m32 -Wl,-eh-frame-hdr -Wl,-m,elf_i386 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIE -pie -L./OpenSSL-For-Android/openssl-1.0.2j/lib/x86 --sysroot=/home/david/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/ -isysroot /home/david/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/ -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -o /tmp/ffconf.mxzx6kFL /tmp/ffconf.x5yr8e11.o -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lm -pthread
/home/david/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lssl
/home/david/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lws2_32
/home/david/ndk/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lgdi32
/tmp/ffconf.x5yr8e11.o:ffconf.JVeoLDmr.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'SSL_library_init'
```

And it seems like it doesn't use the precompiled shared library i passed it(since it's compiled for Android) and doesn't find another instance of openssl, since the sysroot is the Android AOSP one (this is what I am thinking, please correct me if I'm wrong - I'm not experienced enough in this field ) .
How can this be fixed ? I have seen some setups with PKG-Config, but i have no clue as how to configure it correctly.

Comment: The log suggests that ffmpeg is looking for libssl, but the GitHub project you found only contains libcrypto. You can try https://github.com/emileb/OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt instead.

Comment: `-lws2_32 -lgdi32` looks worse: these are Windows libraries, and I cannot tell how they arrive to your configuration. Maybe this is a false alarm and they will be ignored, I cannot tell

Comment: Yup that did the trick, i was able to compile when i used that library instead, just removed the .so file (It would default to them instead). THANK YOU SO MUCH , i have been sitting on this for ages.One last thing, i added the `--disable-asm` flag on the x86 build to fix text relocation.

Comment: Using prebuilt openssl is kind of defeating the purpose of this library. It is expected to provide security to your app; a binary coming from a source that you cannot 100% trust may open a hell of insecurity.

Comment: I will compile openssl from source for production use, this was only a pilot for myself.Thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command line for armeabi-v7a:

```
../../ffmpeg/configure --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile \
  --enable-pthreads --enable-small \
  --arch=arm --enable-armv6 --enable-armv6t2 --enable-vfp \
  --enable-armv5te --enable-inline-asm \
  --enable-neon --enable-thumb --enable-fast-unaligned --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
  --cross-prefix=%NDK_ROOT%/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --sysroot=%NDK_ROOT%/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ \
  --disable-everything --disable-doc --disable-shared --disable-avdevice \
  --disable-postproc --disable-network --disable-iconv --disable-zlib --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-swscale-alpha \
  --enable-demuxer='h264,matroska,mpegts,rawvideo,mpegps,yuv4mpegpipe,flv,mov,mpegvideo,nut,avi' \
  --enable-filter='scale,fps,framestep,pad,crop' --enable-protocol='file,pipe' \
  --enable-muxer='h264,rawvideo,yuv4mpegpipe,matroska,mpegts,mp4,mov,nut,avi' \
  --enable-bsf=h264_mp4toannexb --enable-parser=mpeg4video \
  --enable-encoder=rawvideo --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
  --extra-cflags='-march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -fPIE' \
  --extra-ldflags='-fPIE -pie'
```

And this for x86:

```
../../ffmpeg/configure --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile \
  --enable-pthreads --enable-small \
  --arch=x86 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-yasm \
  --cross-prefix=%NDK_ROOT%/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android- \
  --sysroot=%NDK_ROOT%/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/ \
  --disable-everything --disable-doc --disable-shared --disable-avdevice \
  --disable-postproc --disable-network --disable-iconv --disable-zlib --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-swscale-alpha \
  --enable-demuxer='h264,matroska,mpegts,rawvideo,mpegps,yuv4mpegpipe,flv,mov,mpegvideo,nut,avi' \
  --enable-filter='scale,fps,framestep,pad,crop' --enable-protocol='file,pipe' \
  --enable-muxer='h264,rawvideo,yuv4mpegpipe,matroska,mpegts,mp4,mov,nut,avi' \
  --enable-bsf=h264_mp4toannexb --enable-parser=mpeg4video \
  --enable-encoder=rawvideo --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
  --extra-cflags='-m32  -fPIE' \
  --extra-ldflags='-m32 -Wl,-eh-frame-hdr -Wl,-m,elf_i386 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -fPIE -pie'
```

I prefer to run **configure** not from the **ffmpeg** directory, but rather from `obj/local/armeabi-v7a` and `obj/local/x86` - this way I can keep the object files in separate directories, and can **make** for different ABI without running **./configure** again. I don't need NDK standalone toolchain here.

You need [yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html) to compile for x86. The set of **--enable-** flags suit my current needs, not necessarily your needs.

Comment: Hey, first thank you , this script does the job! Now i want to add https support, so i need to compile it with `--enable-openssl` , so i have to compile openssl separately, and how do i tell ffmpeg configuration about it ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have such setup at hand to paste here.